# How can I iterate each time the user presses a button?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have the following number-guessing game. It's an assignment for a class I'm taking. Every time I run the code, the "You have" + i + "chances remaining..." statements returns i as 0. How can I make it so that every time the user presses the Confirm button, it goes through the loop once and i decreases by 1?
I need to have a loop in the assignment and a reset button!

```
<body>
    <!-- GAME INSTRUCTIONS -->
    <h1>Number Guessing Game</h1>
    <p>A random number between 1 and 100 has been generated. Can you guess it?</p>
    <!-- FORM (Includes button to confirm guess, input box, and output box) -->
    <form id="Input" name="Input">
        <input name="guess" placeholder="Insert your guess" type="number">
        <input name="requestInfo" onclick="getResults()" type="button" value="Confirm">
        <p></p>
        <textarea cols="50" name="results" readonly="true" rows="8"></textarea>
        <p></p><input name="newGame" onclick="resetGame()" type="button" value="Start New Game">
    </form><!-- JAVASCRIPT START -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

// Define variables
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
var turns = 10;

function checkNumber() {
    var guess = parseFloat(document.Input.guess.value);
    while (turns > 0) {
            if (guess == num) {
                turns = 0;
                document.Input.results.value = "Congratulations, you won! The mystery number was " + num + ".";
            } else if (guess < num) {
                turns--;
                document.Input.results.value = "Your guess was too low. Turns remaining: " + turns;
            } else if (guess > num) {
                turns--;
                document.Input.results.value = "Your guess was too high. Turns remaining: " + turns;
            }
    }
}

function resetGame() {
    turns = 10;
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    document.Input.guess.value = "";
    document.Input.results.value = "";
}

function getResults() {
    checkNumber();
}
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: do not use while loop, I think you need if stmt only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare i outside the function

```
var i =5;
function checkNumber() {
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
var guess = parseFloat(document.Input.guess.value);

    while (i > 0) {
        if (guess == num){
            i = 0;
            document.Input.results.value = "Congratulations, you won!";}
        else if (guess < num){
            i--;
            document.Input.results.value = "Your guess was too low. You have " + i + " chances remaining before a new game starts.";
        }
        else if (guess > num){
            i--;
            document.Input.results.value = "Your guess was too high. You have " + i + " chances remaining before a new game starts.";
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need *while* loop at all; just use *if*.

Also, you need to put i outside so that changes are reflected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Define variables
var i = 5;
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
function checkNumber() {

var guess = parseFloat(document.Input.guess.value);

    if(i > 0) {
        if (guess == num){
            i = 0;
            document.Input.results.value = "Congratulations, you won!";}
        else if (guess < num){
            i--;
            document.Input.results.value = "Your guess was too low. You have " + i + " chances remaining before a new game starts.";
        }
        else if (guess > num){
            i--;
            document.Input.results.value = "Your guess was too high. You have " + i + " chances remaining before a new game starts.";
        }
    }

 }
function getResults(){
    checkNumber();
}
</script>
```

Comment: getting a new random number every time the function is called will not yield the desired results. `var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;` needs to be moved out of the function so that it is called only once.

Comment: @sid-m Thanks for that. I was only thinking about the OP's question, not the overall purpose.

Comment: This did work, but I just found out that having a loop is a requirement for the assignment :(

Answer (score 0):

When your function `checkNumber` is called, `num` is initialized and so is `guess`. Then, you are comparing that same `guess` to `num` in the while loop `i` times. You should move this line 
`var guess = parseFloat(document.Input.guess.value);`
inside the while loop.